# (Django) Passing 'context' (basic info) to every page, even forms?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I'm fairly new to Django (using 1.6.2) and I fear that I may be getting into poor practices, so I must ask:

Currently I'm handling some simple views: home, profile. For both of these views, I check if a user is logged in with `request.user`. And if that user is logged in, I pass his info into context{} and send that to the template.

So, do I basically need to do that for every view in which I want to include that information?

```
#views.py 

def home(request):
....etc....
context = { 
    'players' : players, 
    'teams' : teams, 
}

if request.user.is_authenticated():
    p = Player.objects.get(user=request.user)
    if p:
        context['p'] = p
return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

So I basically check if I should ADD that bit of info to the context if it's available before sending it. Problem is, this info is really used as a header, that should be on every page. Is there a way for me to include it on every view without bringing it through context?

*Many thanks in advance. You guys here at StackOverflow have truly helped so many of us get started!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While ndpu has correctly pointed you to context processors to solve the general problem, there doesn't really seem to be any need in this case.

You already have a direct relationship between the current user and the relevant Player: I assume that is a one-to-one. And the `user` object is already passed to the template context by the default context processors, as long as you are using RequestContext (which you are, via the `render` shortcut.) So, without any extra context at all, you can simply do this in your template:

```
{{ user.player }}
```

to get the player.

Comment: Thanks for that, didn't realize I could access the player like that. However: I have a model `TEAM` which consists of Players. In Players I do indeed have a function called `is_on_team(self)`, but I can't correctly access it in the template. I can do user.player.is_on_team() but the `()` is giving a problem. Would I need to make a context_processor as @ndpu kindly mentioned?

Comment: No. As long as the method takes no arguments apart from self), you can call it directly on the template just by missing out the parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a [custom context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors):

```
def foo(request):
    """ 
    Adds Player to context
    """

    context = {'p': None}
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        p = Player.objects.get(user=request.user)
        if p:
            context['p'] = p

    return context
```

and add it to `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` tuple in settings.py (assumed that `foo` placed in context_processors.py module in your application folder):

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    # ...
    "your_app_name.context_processors.foo",
)
```